# Using Feynman-Kac, compute the following:

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $B(t)$ be Brownian Motion and let $\alpha$ be a constant and $T>0$.

Compute $\mathbb{E}_{B_{0} = x}\left[\exp\left(-\alpha \int_0^T B(s)^2 ds\right)\right]$.

I'm just having a hard time with this one, any help?

Comment: A good first step is to actually write down the Feynman-Kac formula as it applies to your expectation. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman–Kac_formula

Comment: What is $B(t)$? any relationship to $W(t)$?

Comment: They are the same, sorry. I made the change.

Answer (score 1):

If you compare your expression with
$$
u(x,t) = E^Q\left[ \int_t^T e^{-  \int_t^r V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau}f(X_r,r)dr + e^{-\int_t^T V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau}\psi(X_T) \Bigg| X_t=x \right]
$$
where $dX = \mu(X,t)\,dt + \sigma(X,t)\,dW^Q$ (this is pasted from the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula) ), we see that in your case the process $X_t$ is simply $B_t$ so $\mu =0$ and $\sigma=1$. Furthermore, $f(x, t)=0$, $V(x)=\alpha x^2$ and terminal condition is $u(x, T)=\psi(x)=1$

Hence
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) + \mu(x,t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t) + \tfrac{1}{2} \sigma^2(x,t) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x,t) -V(x,t) u(x,t) + f(x,t) = 0
$$
reduces to
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) + \tfrac{1}{2}  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x,t) -\alpha x^2 u(x,t) = 0
$$
so we are still left with solving this PDE, which can possibly be solved following [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231450/second-order-linear-partial-differential-equation-partial-t-ut-x-frac12-p?rq=1)